# Arangdb cluster service

Tags: arangodb

After arangodb cluster is running for a period of time it will stop service, the webpage can not be accessed, and will automatically resume access after a period of time.

I use nmon monitor server resources and found that in the period of cessation of services cpu, memory, disk are very free.

Who has encountered this situation?

Here is my start arangodb cluster command

```
arangodb --server.threads=100 --server.storage-engine=rocksdb
arangodb --server.threads=100 --server.storage-engine=rocksdb --cluster.start-coordinator=false --starter.data-dir=/home/arangodb3 --starter.join node23
arangodb --server.threads=100 --server.storage-engine=rocksdb --cluster.start-coordinator=false --starter.data-dir=/home/arangodb3 --starter.join node23
```

Comment: You mean the ArangoDB web interface is sporadically unaccessible, but it recovers from that situation after a while? Can you elaborate a bit? What version of ArangoDB are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: hello,yes, after a period of time the service will automatically recover, I have monitored the server resources, memory, cpu, disk is no problem, I also saw arangodb log and found no exception.

Another problem is cluster I started password verification, but I did not find it automatically generated password.

My version is 3.2.6.

I'm going to cry